# Entity Framework array not being recognized by JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, entity-framework

Hi I am using Entity Framework to get data using repository using

```
 var test=DbContext.Set<tHoliday>.Include("tInfo"); 
   return test.AsQueryable();
```

Which gives the following data 
Data format is fine

```
    {
    •   $id: "1",
    •   $values: 
    [
    o   {
        $id: "2",
        id: 1,
        shcdName: "Main",
       t_holidays: 
    {
        $id: "3",
        $values: 
    [
       {
       $id: "4",
       id: 13,
       description: "Good Friday",
       t_holiday_schd_nameId: 1,
       date: "2105-04-06T00:00:00",
       t_holiday_schd_name: 
    {
       $ref: "2"
    }
       },
       {
       $id: "5",
       id: 14,
       description: "Memorial Day for 2015",
       t_holiday_schd_nameId: 1,
       date: "2105-05-28T00:00:00",
       t_holiday_schd_name: 
    {
       $ref: "2"
    }
       }, }
]
}
o   },
o   {
   $id: "16",
   id: 3,
   shcdName: "Night_2015",
   t_holidays: 
{
   $id: "17",
   $values: [ ]
}
o   },
o   {
   $id: "18",
   id: 2,
   shcdName: "Swing_2015",
   t_holidays: 
{
   $id: "19",
   $values: 
[
   {
   $id: "20",
   id: 1,
   description: "Good Friday",
   t_holiday_schd_nameId: 2,
   date: "2105-04-06T00:00:00",
   t_holiday_schd_name: 
{
   $ref: "18"
}
   },
   {
   $id: "21",
   id: 2,
   description: "Memorial Day for 2015",
   t_holiday_schd_nameId: 2,
   date: "2105-05-28T00:00:00",
   t_holiday_schd_name: 
{
   $ref: "18"
}


]
}
o   }
]
}
```

On my front end I am using javascript library when it gets this array it doesnt recognize it being JSON array and gives following error

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object
```

Please let me know how I can convert this to JSON array or get it in JSON array in EF Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your array (the data you showed) is wrapped in a top level object

```
{...}
```

On the server side, I think just leaving the .AsQueryable call and returning DbContext.Set.Include("tInfo") should do you.

On the front end you can use a transformResponse function in your resource:

```
angular.module('services', ['ngResource']).
factory("someService", function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        '/', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function(data, headers){

                return data.$values;
            }
        }
    }

    );
});
```

Comment: I have on front end  $scope.holi=holidayRepo.getdetails.query({}, function(data) { $scope.hold=data});  so how do I apply response.$value to it? like  in $scope.hili=response.$value(data);

Comment: check your angular resource. The server is definitely sending back an object not an array.

Comment: okay in my resource I tried $resource('api/holiday/getdetails', {}, {method: 'GET', isArray: false}}).response.$values   now it gives me error TypeError: Cannot read property '$values' of undefined ..... what am i doing wrong here

Comment: Since the server response is not west your angular resource is expecting, you need to transform it. Look up the documentation for transformResponse.